# PDFBOX after adding PDAnnotationLinks file size is increased twice

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm working on Java project and I have following situation:

1. I have existing PDF file generated with apache FOP. Inside there are bookmarks, which I'm getting with :

   ```
   Map<String, PDAction> actionsMap = new HashMap<String, PDAction>();
   PDDocumentOutline bookmarks = doc1.getDocumentCatalog().getDocumentOutline();
   PDOutlineItem item = bookmarks.getFirstChild();
   while(item != null ){
      actionsMap.put(item.getTitle(), item.getAction());
      item = item.getNextSibling();
   }
   ```
2. I'm opening second file (again FOP generated) with PDFBOX 2.0.0 and add 3 PDAnnotationLinks to specific parts of the text. The file is single page with few diagrams. Then I add actions from point 1

   ```
   PDPage page = (PDPage) diagramDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0);
   //objCoordinates is retrieved from another class with PDFTextStripper
   Iterator entries = objCoordinates.entrySet().iterator();
   while (entries.hasNext()) {
     Entry entry = (Entry) entries.next();
     String key = (String) entry.getKey();
     PDAnnotationLink txtLink = new PDAnnotationLink();
     PDBorderStyleDictionary borderULine = new PDBorderStyleDictionary();
     borderULine.setWidth(0);
     txtLink.setBorderStyle(borderULine);
     PDActionGoTo action = (PDActionGoTo) actionsMap.get(key);
     txtLink.setAction(action);

     final float[] quads = (float[]) entry.getValue();
     PDRectangle rect = new PDRectangle();
     rect.setLowerLeftX(quads[0]);
     rect.setLowerLeftY(quads[5]);
     rect.setUpperRightX(quads[2]);
     rect.setUpperRightY(quads[1]);
     txtLink.setRectangle(rect);

     page.getAnnotations().add(txtLink);
   }
   ```

After saving the second file, the links are working, but the file size is doubled. 
PDF version is 1.6. The file already have filter FlateDecode.
I did try online PDF files comparison (initial file and result file with links) but the result is that files have no difference. 
When I open the files with text editor there are
- original file - 1 Type/Page/ instance
- result file - 18 /Type /Page instances
My guess is that PDFBOX is adding some extra (duplicate?) information.

If anyone has encountered this issue I would appreciate advice.

Thanks

Comment: It's difficult without the file, but my feeling is that when you do PDActionGoTo action = (PDActionGoTo) actionsMap.get(key); you are referencing a page from the other file. "page is an indirect reference to a page object" => you should make sure that the destination of your Goto action is a page of your own document. Btw just in case, you mentioned "2.0.0", I hope it's the released version and not RC3.

Comment: Hi Tilman, Yes, I'm using released 2.0.0 version, but the issue is else where. As you correctly said Goto action should be a page of your own document and I'm pointing to page from another document... Thank you for pointing this out. I'll have to rework my code and read more about PDFBOX

Comment: Your second file has only one page, so it should be easy to assign the PDPage parameter of the PDPageDestination of the goto action. action.setDestination(page).

Comment: Yes, that is a variant. 
The whole picture is: File 1 contains details about objects and have bookmarks. File 2 contains single page diagram. I'm merging two files.
The point is when user click on a diagram object he should go to details.
My mistake is that I'm first editing file 2 (diagram) with links from file 1 and after that merging two files. The new approach is first merge the two files and the add links. 
Now the result file size is normal.
Thanks again for the help :-)

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please answer the question yourself so that'll make a nice example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just wondering how to give you a credit Tilman ... :-)
Ok, I have reworked and simplified the code so I can post it here. 
Hope it is clear

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Map.Entry;

    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.action.PDAction;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.action.PDActionGoTo;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationLink;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDBorderStyleDictionary;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.documentnavigation.outline.PDDocumentOutline;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.documentnavigation.outline.PDOutlineItem;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;

    /**
     * @author micky
     *
     * The class merges PDF files
     *  - one file with item details info
     *  - one or more files with items diagrams
     *  
     *   Purpose is to merge diagram files into item details file and create links 
     *   from the items in diagrams to item details
     */
    public class PDFReportHyperlinks {

         public static void main(String[] args){

             PDDocument reportDocument = null;
             try {

                 String reportFileName = "D:/ItemsDetails.pdf";

                 Map<String, PDAction> actionsMap = new HashMap<String, PDAction>();
                 reportDocument = PDDocument.load(new File(reportFileName));

                 // Get the bookmarks i.e. existing GoTo actions
                 PDDocumentOutline bookmarks = reportDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getDocumentOutline();
                 PDOutlineItem item = bookmarks.getFirstChild();
                 while(item != null ){
                     actionsMap.put(item.getTitle(), item.getAction());
                     item = item.getNextSibling();
                 }

                 // Diagram files, they have single page
                 List diagamFiles = new ArrayList<String>() {{
                        add("D:/Diagram_1.pdf");
                        add("D:/Diagram_2.pdf");
                        add("D:/Diagram_3.pdf");
                 }};

                 Iterator diagramsIt = diagamFiles.iterator();
                 while (diagramsIt.hasNext()) {
                     String diagramName = (String) diagramsIt.next();

                     //--<Import diagram>---------------------------------
                     PDDocument sourceDocument = PDDocument.load(new File(diagramName));
                     PDPage pp = (PDPage) sourceDocument .getDocumentCatalog().getPages().get(0);
                     PDPage page = reportDocument.importPage(pp);

                     //--<Create links from diagrams to objects>---------------------------------

                     // TextStripper is separate class extending PDFTextStripper
                     // It is searching for items names and returning Map with their coordinates
                     TextStripper stripper = new TextStripper(sourceDocument,
                             new ArrayList<String>() {{
                                 add("Item1_Name");
                                 add("Item2_Name");
                                 add("Item3_Name");
                                 add("Item4_Name");
                                 add("Item5_Name");
                             }});

                     Map<String, float[]> objCoordinates = stripper.getObjCoordinates();

                     Iterator entries = objCoordinates.entrySet().iterator();
                     while (entries.hasNext()) {
                         Entry entry = (Entry) entries.next();
                         String key = (String) entry.getKey();

                         PDAnnotationLink txtLink = new PDAnnotationLink();
                         PDBorderStyleDictionary borderULine = new PDBorderStyleDictionary();
                         borderULine.setWidth(0);
                         txtLink.setBorderStyle(borderULine);
                         PDActionGoTo action = (PDActionGoTo) actionsMap.get(key);
                         txtLink.setAction(action);

                         final float[] quads = (float[]) entry.getValue();
                         PDRectangle rect = new PDRectangle();
                         rect.setLowerLeftX(quads[0]);
                         rect.setLowerLeftY(quads[5]);
                         rect.setUpperRightX(quads[2]);
                         rect.setUpperRightY(quads[1]);
                         txtLink.setRectangle(rect);

                         page.getAnnotations().add(txtLink);
                     }

                     //--<Create bookmarks for new pages (diagrams)>---------------------------------
                     PDOutlineItem menuItem = new PDOutlineItem();
                     menuItem.setTitle(diagramName);
                     menuItem.setDestination(page);
                     bookmarks.addLast(menuItem);
                     menuItem.openNode();
                     bookmarks.openNode();

                 }

                 reportDocument.save(new File(reportFileName));
                 reportDocument.close();

                 // Alternative merging documents example not feasible in this case
                 //PDFMergerUtility ut = new PDFMergerUtility();
                 //ut.addSource(reportFileName);
                 //diagramsIt = diagamFiles.iterator();
                 //while (diagramsIt.hasNext()) {
                 //  String diagramName = (String) diagramsIt.next();
                 //  ut.addSource(diagramName);
                 // }
                 //ut.setDestinationFileName(reportFileName);
                 //ut.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly());

                System.out.println("COMPLETED");

             } catch (Exception e) {
                 System.out.println(e);
             } finally {
                 try {
                     reportDocument.close();
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     System.out.println(e);
                 }
            }
        }
    }
```